# What advantages / disadvantages is there adding a 'www' prefix to your domain name?

Tags: 7, .htaccess

currently i am replicating my site and my .htaccess file has www redirection prefix enabled, but if im copying this to my local, it will prefix my site with www.localhost. I was wondering would it be ideal to just turn this www rewriting prefix off on both sites so i don't have to edit the .htaccess file everytime i do a clone to my local?

what are some issues i might have when turning it off or on? i think from a seo perspective i should have it on, but can someone clarify this?

Comment: This really has nothing to do with Drupal, and has been discussed at length on the net.  If you would like it to be moved, please flag with a custom reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no advantages. The www prefix is actually a subdomain.

Google considers example.com and www.example.com to be separate sites. From an SEO perspective, choose one and run with it. In your Google Webmaster Tools account you can list both, and configure Google treat them as the same.

Other search engines do not have the tools.

I have my servers configured to respond without the prefix, to rewrite the URL's if the prefix is requested, and to issue a permanent redirect.

If you try to honor both forms, then you give the appearance of duplicate content, and that would have a negative effect on SEO.

Comment: so this means i would have to update my local's .htaccess file so it wont do a www.localhost rewrite then.

Comment: Search engines do not index local host. You can do what you want on a local copy. When you publish to the web it is a different story. Best to co-ordinate the two, but there is no 'Must Do' here.